# Getting list of all properties of a node using libxml

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm having trouble to find a way to extract a list of all properties of a node without knowing what they're called.

I'm extracting single known properties using:

`xmlGetProp(cur, (const xmlChar*)"nodename")`

But how to get a list of all properties using libxml2?

Regards,
marius

Comment: I'd advise to add a tag specifying the language you're using

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply loop through the node's properties list, ie:

```
xmlNodePtr Node = ...;
for(xmlAttrPtr attr = Node->properties; NULL != attr; attr = attr->next)
{
    ... do something with attr ...
    ... the name of the attribute is in attr->name ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, does not appear to be a method that does this (though oddly there is xmlFreePropList function), but the xmlNode structure has a pointer to a list of the properties (attributes) of the node.   You can probably get a pointer to that structure.